# Set variable value with serial?

Tags: serial, programming, sketch

so I need to make a arduino program, generates 2 random numbers, makes a + calculation with them and asks user the right answer. If the answer is right AKA Calculation==User Answer, then led is set to LOW, and serialprint sent. If its wrong, Led lights up and serialprint sent again. It works if i set the variables manually etc. But the I think the problem is with my serialRead, somehow it doesnt set the value it got from the user as the value of the variable (Luku4)

Here is the code, I hope you can help me.

```
int Luku1 = 0;
int Luku2 = 0;  
int Luku3 = 0;  //Summa
int Luku4 = 0; //Vastaus
const int ledPin = 13;
byte i = 0;

void setup() {

  for (i=0; i<4; i++){
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
}

randomSeed(analogRead(0));
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Arvotaan 2 satunnaislukua ja summataan ne yhteen. Kerro oikea vastaus");
}



void loop() {
  Serial.println("Arvotaan 2 satunnaislukua");
  Luku1 = random(1,5);
  Luku2 = random(1,5);
  Serial.println(Luku1);
  Serial.println("+");
  Serial.println(Luku2);
  Luku3 = Luku1 + Luku2;
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Mika on vastaus?");
  Luku4 = Serial.read();
    while(Serial.available() == 0){}

  if (Luku4==Luku3) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("Oikea vastaus");
    delay(2000);
  }

  else{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Vaarin");
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  }
}
```

Comment: You should move the `Serial.read` to after the  "wait for serial input"-line. Secondly. `Serial.read` will return a character, not a number. So you have to convert the ascii value of the letters "0"-"9" to the integer value of 0-9. This can be done by subtracting 48, as "0" is ascii code nr 48.

Comment: Oh, never heard of that. Thanks alot, it worked!

Comment: but it still works only for one digit and not for a number. use parseInt https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/

Comment: These could all by byte, vs int, as they will not be more than 255:int Luku1 = 0;
int Luku2 = 0;  
int Luku3 = 0;  //Summa
int Luku4 = 0; //Vastaus
const int ledPin = 13;

Comment: And why do you need to set this pin to an  output 4 times? Once is enough   for (i=0; i<4; i++){
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
}

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a byte which was read through uart with a number. If you send number '5' through uart, you won't get number 5, but character '5'. To convert single character to number, you can do following:

```
Luku4 = Serial.read(); // '0' .. '9'
Luku4 = Luku4 - '0'; // 0..9
```

But this will work only for single digit numbers, for more robust solution please refer to [readString function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString) to see how you can read strings from UART and to function [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) which converts string to number.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading Serial before you check that there is anything valid to read:

```
Luku4 = Serial.read();
while(Serial.available() == 0){}
```

Try swapping those two lines.

Comment: Swapped, Still not working. Only gives the "else", no matter what I input. Thanks for the help still.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines

```
Luku4 = Serial.read();
while(Serial.available() == 0){}
```

to these lines

```
while(Serial.available() == 0){}
Luku4 = Serial.parseInt();
```

As shown in the [Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt), Serial.parseInt() will read a number from Serial. If a non-number character is entered it will return 0.